# jQuery Framingham equation return NaN as a result

Tags: jquery

I am programming a medical application for a clinic, and I want to make a page for CVD, MI(Myocardial Infarction), Stroke, CHD_Death, CVD_Death, BNF and ASSIGN (Cardio Vascular disease).

The equation provide by the Doctor is the Framingham Equation:

```
var framingham = 100*(1-Math.exp(-Math.exp((Math.log(time_period)-(18.8144+(-1.2146*(1-genderVal))+(-1.8443*Math.log(age))+(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age))+(0.3668*Math.log(age)*(1-genderVal))
+(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age)*(1-genderVal))+(-1.4032*Math.log(systolic))+(-0.3899*smokerVal)+(-0.539*Math.log(total_chol/hdl_chol))
+(-0.3036*diabetes)+(-0.1697*diabetesVal*(1-genderVal))+(-0.3362*lvhVal)+(0*lvhVal*genderVal)))/(Math.exp(0.6536)
*Math.exp(-0.2402*(18.8144+(-1.2146*(1-genderVal))+(-1.8443*Math.log(age))
+(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age))+(0.3668*smokerVal)+(-0.539*Math.log(total_chol/hdl_chol))
+(-0.3036*diabetesVal)+(-0.1697*diabetesVal*(1-genderVal))
+(-0.3362*lvhVal)+(0*lvhVal*genderVal)))))));

console.log(framingham);
```

First, there is inside the function some part that are multiplied by 0, which will nullify it. I tested it and at the console I've got the result of: NaN or Not a Number.

I tested the variables and the computer is reading them properly.

1. Math.log(): is the natural logarithm;
2. Math.exp(): is the exponential;
3. genderVal: If male =>1, if female =>0;
4. lvh: Left ventricular hypertrophy=>1 if exist, 0 if not;
5. Systolic_bp: Systolic Blood Pressure;
6. total_chol: total cholesterol;
7. hdl_chol: HDL Cholesterol;
8. diabetesVal: 1 if it does exist, 0 if not.

Here is the full script:

```
$("#calculate_add").on('click', function()
        {
            var genderVal = 0;
            var smokerVal = 0;
            var diabetesVal = 0;
            var lvhVal = 0;

            var time_period = $("#time_period").val();
            var gender = $("#gender").val();
            var age = $("#age").val();
            var smoker = $("#smoker").val();
            var systolic = $("#sbp").val();
            var total_chol = $("#total_chol").val();
            var hdl_chol = $("#hdl_chol").val();
            var diabetes = $("#diabetes").val();
            var lvh = $("#lvh").val();
            if(time_period == "" || time_period<4 || time_period>12)
            {
                $("#time_period").css('border-color', 'red');
                $("#time_period").focus();
            }

            else if(systolic == "" || systolic == 0)
            {
                $("#sbp").css('border-color', 'red');
                $("#sbp").focus();
            }

            else if(total_chol == "" || total_chol == 0)
            {
                $("#total_chol").css('border-color', 'red');
                $("#total_chol").focus();
            }

            else if(hdl_chol == "" || hdl_chol == 0)
            {
                $("#hdl_chol").css('border-color', 'red');
                $("#hdl_chol").focus();
            }

            else if(diabetes == "select")
            {
                $("#diabetes").css('border-color', 'red');
                $("#diabetes").focus();
            }

            else if(lvh == "select")
            {
                $("#lvh").css('border-color', 'red');
                $("#lvh").focus();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#time_period").css('border-color', '#0090ff');
                $("#sbp").css('border-color', '#0090ff');
                $("#total_chol").css('border-color', '#0090ff');
                $("#hdl_chol").css('border-color', '#0090ff');
                $("#diabetes").css('border-color', '#0090ff');
                $("#lvh").css('border-color', '#0090ff');

                if(gender == "Male")
                {
                    genderVal = 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    genderVal = 0;
                }
                if(smoker == "Yes")
                {
                    smokerVal = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    smokerVal = 0;
                }
                if(diabetes == "yes")
                {
                    diabetesVal = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    diabetesVal = 0;
                }
                if(lvh == "yes")
                {
                    lvhVal = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    lvhVal = 0;
                }
                console.log(genderVal);
                console.log(diabetesVal);
                console.log(lvhVal);

                //Formula Calculation
                var framingham = 100*(1-Math.exp(-Math.exp((Math.log(time_period)-(18.8144+(-1.2146*(1-genderVal))+(-1.8443*Math.log(age))+(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age))+(0.3668*Math.log(age)*(1-genderVal))
                    +(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age)*(1-genderVal))+(-1.4032*Math.log(systolic))+(-0.3899*smokerVal)+(-0.539*Math.log(total_chol/hdl_chol))
                    +(-0.3036*diabetes)+(-0.1697*diabetesVal*(1-genderVal))+(-0.3362*lvhVal)+(0*lvhVal*genderVal)))/(Math.exp(0.6536)
                    *Math.exp(-0.2402*(18.8144+(-1.2146*(1-genderVal))+(-1.8443*Math.log(age))
                    +(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age))+(0.3668*smokerVal)+(-0.539*Math.log(total_chol/hdl_chol))
                    +(-0.3036*diabetesVal)+(-0.1697*diabetesVal*(1-genderVal))
                    +(-0.3362*lvhVal)+(0*lvhVal*genderVal)))))));
                console.log(framingham);
            }
        });
```

I can't communicate with the doctor for few  reasons and can't find the real equation online.

**EDIT**

I split the function up:

```
var var1 = (18.8144+(-1.2146*(1-genderVal))+(-1.8443*Math.log(age))
                    +(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age))+(0.3668*smokerVal)+(-0.539*Math.log(total_chol/hdl_chol))
                    +(-0.3036*diabetesVal)+(-0.1697*diabetesVal*(1-genderVal))
                    +(-0.3362*lvhVal)+(0*lvhVal*genderVal));
                var var2 = (Math.exp(0.6536)
                    *Math.exp(-0.2402*var1));
                var var3 = (Math.log(time_period)-(18.8144+(-1.2146*(1-genderVal))+(-1.8443*Math.log(age))+(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age))+(0.3668*Math.log(age)*(1-genderVal))
                    +(0*Math.log(age)*Math.log(age)*(1-genderVal))+(-1.4032*Math.log(systolic))+(-0.3899*smokerVal)+(-0.539*Math.log(total_chol/hdl_chol))
                    +(-0.3036*diabetes)+(-0.1697*diabetesVal*(1-genderVal))+(-0.3362*lvhVal)+(0*lvhVal*genderVal)))/var2
                var framingham = 100*(1-Math.exp(-Math.exp(var3)));
                console.log(var1);
                console.log(var2);
                console.log(var3);
                console.log(framingham);
```

`var3` and framingham gave me NaN and the others gave me decimal numbers.

Comment: My take on this would be... **First step**: explicitly convert all values you read from your text boxes to numbers. Text boxes contain strings, even if these strings only consist of the characters 0-9. **Next step**: NaN is sticky. If any part of a calculation is NaN, the overall result will likely be NaN as well. Pull apart the equation and figure out which part is NaN. Eliminate the reason. **Note**: Use the debugger built into your browser to your advantage. Set a break point in front of the calculation and inspect all the individual values.

Comment: See my edit. I split them up